Making a tuple of references out of another tuple by condition
I have a templated structure ContainerInner that has a tuple with vectors of types from its variadic template and a structure Container that contains a tuple of ContainerInner, specified in its template. The code looks like this:
template<typename... Args>
struct ContainerInner
{
    std::tuple<std::vector<Args>...> m_elements;

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool containsOne()
    {
        return (std::is_same_v<T, Args> || ...);
    }

    template<typename... T>
    static constexpr bool contains()
    {
        return (containsOne<T>() && ...);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T> &get()
    {
        return std::get<std::vector<T>>(m_elements);
    }
};

template<typename... T>
struct ArgList {
    template<typename... TTS>
    using add = ArgList<T..., ContainerInner<TTS...>>;
};
    
template<typename ListArgs>
struct Container;

template<typename... Args>
struct Container<ArgList<Args...>>
{
    std::tuple<Args...> m_containers;

    // It also crashes with std::tuple<Args&...> return type
    template<typename... T>
    inline auto getTuples()
    {
        auto tpl = std::make_tuple<Args&...>(std::get<Args>(m_containers)...);
        return tpl;
    }

    template<typename... T>
    ContainerInner<T...> &get()
    {
        return std::get<ContainerInner<T...>>(m_containers);
    }
};

using MyArgList = ArgList<>
    ::add<char, int>
    ::add<char, float>
    ::add<char, int, float>;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{    
    Container <MyArgList> cnt;

    auto arr = cnt.getTuples<float>();

    std::get<ContainedType<char, int>>(arr).get<int>().push_back(3);

    std::cout << typeid(arr).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << cnt.get<char, int>().get<int>().size() << std::endl;
}

I want to change getTuples method so that it would return a tuple with references to all ContainerInner from m_containers that contain specified types, which is a condition handled by static contains method. I thought I could use a concept like this:
template<typename InnerCnt, typename T>
concept ContainedType = 
    requires(T a, InnerCnt b) {
       b.contains<T>();
    };

to recursively iterate over variadic template and use std::tuple_cat to build final array, but didnt figure out how to do it. How can I solve this problem?
EDIT. I solved it, but probably not in the optimal way. I added Query wrapper over tuple with overloaded operator+ and used it for unfolding:
    template<typename... Args>
struct Query
{
    std::tuple<Args...> m_tpl;

    template<typename... TT>
    constexpr inline auto operator+(const Query<TT...> &rhs_)
    {
        return Query<Args..., TT...>(std::tuple_cat(m_tpl, rhs_.m_tpl));
    }

    template<typename... TT>
    constexpr inline auto &get()
    {
        return std::get<ContainerInner<TT...>&>(m_tpl);
    }
};

template<typename LST, typename CONTAINER_INNER>
constexpr inline auto getQueryElem(CONTAINER_INNER &t_)
{
    return Query<>();
}

template<typename LST, typename CONTAINER_INNER> requires Contained<CONTAINER_INNER, LST>
constexpr inline auto getQueryElem(CONTAINER_INNER &t_)
{
    return Query(std::tuple<CONTAINER_INNER&>(t_));
}


// Inside Container
template<typename... T>
constexpr inline auto getTuples()
{
    return (getQueryElem<Typelist<T...>>(std::get<Args>(m_containers)) + ...);
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
  Container <MyArgList> cnt;
  auto arr = cnt.getTuples<int>();
  std::cout << typeid(arr).name() << std::endl;

  cnt.get<char, int>().get<int>().push_back(5);
  arr.get<char, int>().get<int>().push_back(-99);

  std::cout << cnt.get<char, int>().get<int>() << std::endl;
  std::cout << arr.get<char, int>().get<int>() << std::endl;
}

It seems to work, but i'm not sure how well does compiler optimize this, it might actually create temporary Queries during unfolding in runtime

b.template contains<T>();?

@Jarod42 I've already fixed it, it compiled on msvc but not on gcc or clang

Can you provide runnable code (possibly with link)? So we can experiment. Unclear for me whar do you expect that getTuples returns...

@Jarod42 Sure, here's link . This code accesses vector directly and through the returned reference and checks that its the same vector and not a copy. It returns what is expected, minus gcc's typeid name formatting

Issues from getTuples():

it is template but doesn't use its parameters. can be removed.
std::make_tuple is intended to deduced its parameter, you want std::tuple directly:

auto getTuples()
{
    auto tpl = std::tuple<Args&...>(std::get<Args>(m_containers)...);
    return tpl;
}

Demo
or use std::tie:
auto getTuples()
{
    return std::tie(std::get<Args>(m_containers)...);
}

Demo
From your edit, it seems you want to filter (at compile time) some elements of the tuple, so using std::tuple_cat with function which return empty tuple or tuple with the element might help:
template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
auto filter(ContainerInner<Us...>& c)
{
    if constexpr (ContainerInner<Us...>::template contains<Ts...>()) {
        return std::tie(c);
    } else {
        return std::tuple<>{};
    }
}

And then
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto getTuples()
{
    return std::tuple_cat(filter<Ts...>(std::get<Args>(m_containers))...);
})

Demo

Look at getTuples after edit, it uses its parameter, I just didnt know how to use it at the moment

Edited to add your filter.

Thanks a lot, i didnt know you could do it with 1 function with if constexpr here

Alternative would be overload (with SFINAE or tag dispatching).
